# Kafka from MSSQL no topics created using JDBCSourceConnector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have connected Kafka with MSSQl using JDBC connector. The connector has been successfully connected and the status is running. But when i curled port `http://ip:8083/topics`  I am getting 404 not found error `"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}`.

What could be the reason for this?

This is the connector configuration.

```
{"name":"test-mssql-source","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","mode":"incrementing","incrementing.column.name":"id","topic.prefix":"test-mssql-","tasks.max":"1","poll.interval.ms":"100","name":"test-mssql-source","connection.url":"jdbc:sqlserver://ip;Database=TEST_KAFKA;user=user;password=root","value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"},"tasks":[{"connector":"test-mssql-source","task":0}],"type":"source"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing Kafka Connect with the Confluent REST Proxy.

[Connect API has no `/topics` endpoint](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest)

And if you did curl the REST Proxy, you would at least get an empty array when there are no topics

Comment: How do i curl that... Please help... I couldnot find the curl command.

Comment: curl what? Kafka Connect does not have the endpoint you are looking for... By default, [the REST Proxy runs on port **8082**](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/quickstart.html). Connect is on **8083**. The [complete API for the REST Proxy is here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html), so if you are having issues finding it, please provide feedback to Confluent through the links at the bottom of the site.

Comment: I curl the REST proxy but it is showing `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8082: Connection refused`

Comment: Okay, well, I suggest going over to the documentation, because it seems it's not running. From your question, it's not clear that it was started. I am also curious what tutorials you're following that say you can go to that url to find any information

Comment: Using the url would be my mistake. I don't have much idea about kafka.I could connect kafka with JDBC sql server. But i could not see the generated topics. So i am searching the way to see the generated topics. Till now i am not clear how could i see it.. :(

Comment: Most people would use `kafka-topics --list`, as documentated on the Apache Kafka website